# jquery data tables not working in IE6 although its working IE7 & firefox

Tags: jquery

I am using data tables for pagination. But this is not working in IE6.
The problem is in IE6, the checked checkboxes are not persisting if move to another page, but this working fine with IE7 & mozilla

```
var selectedunmatchParty = new Array();
$('#unmatchpartygrp input:checked').each(function() {
    selectedunmatchParty.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to sound like a troll but IE6 is the problem
People should have upgraded years ago.

Fixing for IE6 in this day and age is only worsening the problem by making people feel it's normal to drive around in a Model T Ford . . .

As for a fix 'because you have to' try this: http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=106&page=1

Sorry ^^ wrong link, http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=185 should be the one.

Stupid bosses still using IE6 ;)

Comment: Hi the_jinx, there is no solution in that page ...what should I do? Most of my clients are using IE6...

Comment: Find better clients . . or convince them to come into this century.

Perhaps give them chrome-frame (which is a problem in itself, but never mind).. updated link in Answer!

Comment: by the advise in the above link, I created a js array for storing checked items value to persist in moving to other pages. I am calling the js function on all checkbox click time, but when I move to another page, the array got cleared not showing old checked values. I pasted code above. help please

Comment: You should not just store then, nut also retrieve them . . on moving to an other page . .
Is that the problem?

Comment: I am not clear with what you are saying...my understanding is that since page is not refreshed the data on js array keeps storing there, so I call this js function on check box click and also when we click the nextpage button also...where I went wrong!!!

Comment: +1 for calling yourself a troll and saving everyone else the effort. ;)